# mysqldump not working from cron job

Tags: mysql, cron

I want to auto backup my database using cron job. Here is my cronjob command which runs every minute.

```
* * * *  * /usr/bin/mysqldump  -u username -password dbname >  /var/www/backup/db_`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`.sql
```

My database username and password are also correct. It works fine when I run the same command in terminal but it not working through cron job. Is there anything wrong with my command?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried checking the logs?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs How to find cron job logs?

Comment: as far as i know you need do run the command by a user. there is none given in your command. i guess that * is not valid as user

Comment: @KrishnaKarki should be under `/var/log` somewhere and as @meistermuh said - check file permissions on directory and script

Comment: replace `* * * *  *` with `* * * * *` and see what happens